# How to check if a message.author is a bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is my **on_message_edit** event for my logs. Although it works fine I  was wondering how could I make it not trigger when a bot edits a message.

```
 @commands.Cog.listener()
 async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
        channel1 = await self.bot.logs.find(before.guild.id)  # this is for my db
        channel = channel1["channel"]  # also for my db
        logs = self.bot.get_channel(channel)  # also for my db
        if before.content.author == self.bot:
            return
        if before.content != after.content:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message edited", color=0xe74c3c)
            embed.add_field(name="Previous message", value=f"{before.content}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="New message", value=f"{after.content}", inline=False)
            await logs.send(embed=embed)
```

**Thank you for your time :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `discord.Member.bot`. It returns `True` if a member is bot.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
    if before.author.bot:
        return
    ...
```

## Reference

- [`discord.Member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot)